# str_replace matches incorrect part of string

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm having some issues with **str_replace**, when trying to automatically put backticks around table- and fieldnames.

Assuming i have the following arrays:

```
$match = array('rooms.roomID','r_rooms.roomID');
$replace = array('`rooms`.`roomID`','`r_rooms`.`roomID`');
$subject = 'rooms.roomID = r_rooms.roomID';

str_replace($match,$replace,$subject);
```

The result that I expect is:

```
`rooms`.`roomID` = `r_rooms`.`roomID`
```

But instead I'm getting this:

```
`rooms`.`roomID` = r_`rooms`.`roomID`
```

However if i change **r_rooms** to **r_ooms**, my result is as expected

```
`rooms`.`roomID` = `r_ooms`.`roomID`
```

I've tried the same precedure, using **preg_replace**, but this gives me the same output aswell.

Comment: Either switch the order of the values (`rooms.roomID` is part of `r_rooms.roomID`, so should come later), or do a `preg_replace` surrounding it with word boundaries (`\b`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. First replaced value is rooms.roomID to `rooms`.`roomID` (2 times)
Change order of $match and $replace tables to get expected result

```
$match = array('r_rooms.roomID','rooms.roomID');
$replace = array('`r_rooms`.`roomID`','`rooms`.`roomID`');
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick fix would be reordering `$match` and `$replace` arrays like this...

```
$match = array('r_rooms.roomID', 'rooms.roomID');
$replace = array('`r_rooms`.`roomID`', '`rooms`.`roomID`');
```

The problem of the original approach is that `str_replace` processes `$match` array element by element, at each step trying to cover the whole string - and replaces the found parts *immediately*.

As `rooms.roomID` string 'matches' both `[rooms.roomID]` and `r_[rooms.roomID]`, and replaces these accordingly, the second iteration will have nothing to do.

---

As I said, that's only a quick fix. In this case I'd try to use `preg_replace` instead, surrounding the actual search with `\b` (word boundary anchors).

Then again, with all due respect I smell XY problem here. Aren't you trying to make your own routine for `quoteIdentifier`? That was already solved (and asked here a lot of times).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that did it! - But I think I'll go with Wrikken's solution, using the preg_replace and surround it with word boundaries

Comment: I probably am, I just didn't know it was called that - Again thanks!